# Query a field with comma separated values

Tags: mysql

A `table` has stored coordinates in a single `value` field like

```
ID  key     value
============================
20  coords  38.5931,-90.2226
21  coords  35.7977,-78.6253
22  coords  37.555,-122.2687
23  coords  41.1412,-73.2637
24  coords  47.4716,8.2925
29  coords  42.3626,-71.0843
30  coords  -27.6333,-48.65
```

**What's the best way to query this field?**

Basically I would like to get all entries where lat > 38 and lng < 0 like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE key = 'coords' AND my_lat_value > 38 AND my_lng_value < 0
```

Unfortunately there's no way to split them in dedicate fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function to parse the field.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ',', 1) AS DECIMAL(10,2)),
       CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ',', -1) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: do I get a float where I can calculate with?

Comment: you can convert the values then, see my edit to the answer